# Why isn't a django database object created?

Tags: python, django, database, manytomanyfield

I'm trying to create a drink database app in django. I have created a drinkRecipe model with ManyToManyField relation to Ingredients model. I can successfully add Ingredients to database via app UI, but for some reason when creating a drink, I get no errors nor do I add the drink to database, instead of going back to the index page only the URL of current page changes.
What am I missing?

models.py:

```
class DrinkRecipe(models.Model):
drinkName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredients)
utensil = models.IntegerField(choices=requiredUtensil, default=0)
preparation = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

def __str__(self):
    return self.drinkName
```

forms.py:

```
class DrinkForm(forms.Form):
name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label="Name:")
utensil = forms.ChoiceField(choices=requiredUtensil, label="Required utensil:")
ingredients = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Ingredients.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
preparation = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

views.py:

```
class AddDrinkView(View):

def get(self, request):
    form_drinks = DrinkForm()
    drinks_list = DrinkRecipe.objects.all()
    context = {
        'form_drinks': form_drinks,
        'drinks_list': drinks_list,
    }
    return render(request, 'shakerApp/add_drink.html', context)

def post(self, request):
    form_drinks = DrinkForm(request.POST)

    if form_drinks.is_valid():

        DrinkRecipe.objects.create(
            name=form_drinks.cleaned_data['name'],
            utensil=form_drinks.cleaned_data['utensil'],
            ingredients=form_drinks.cleaned_data['ingredients'],
            preparation=form_drinks.cleaned_data['preparation']
        )
    else:
        messages.error(request, "Drink form is invalid.")

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('shakerApp:index'))
```

*edited to change brackets per @Bono suggestion

**EDIT: So, I'm a moron and didn't add `method='post'` to  in the template. That solved the part that I stayed in the add_drink view after hitting submit, but, the database still is not updated.

Comment: You should probably change the way you access `cleaned_data`, since right now you're calling it instead of accessing its properties. I.e. try `cleaned_data['name']` or `cleaned_data.get('name')`. I'm guessing you should see an error in your logs somewhere because of this, which is probably also why it's not redirecting (since it's breaking).

Comment: While you were right and I used wrong brackets, it doesn't seem to have any effect on this matter.

Comment: Just to confirm. Are you actually rendering messages somewhere in your template? Otherwise you won't see when the form in invalid, you can do this by adding `{{ messages }}` I believe in your template. Or `{{ form.errors }}` in your template to see if there are any errors. Otherwise I recommend writing some debug statements (i.e. `print()`) to walk through several parts of the code to see where something goes wrong (you will be able to see this in your logs).

Comment: @Bono yes, I have a base.html file that is extended in add_ingredients.html template. Like so:
`{% if messages %}
{% for message in messages %}
<h4>{{ message }}</h4>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there was actually a problem with form.
The DrinkRecipe model consists of ManyToManyField, and was not properly used in the corresponding form.
Basically, `ModelChoiceField` couldn't work with `widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()`. Thank you to @ThePjot for pointing me in the right direction.
Corrected below.

forms.py:

```
class DrinkForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label="Name:")
    utensil = forms.ChoiceField(choices=requiredUtensil, label="Required utensil:")
    ingredients = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Ingredients.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
    )
    preparation = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Answer (score 0):

> instead of going back to the index page only the URL of current page changes. What am I missing?

Probable causes:

1. The form is not valid but that is not handled properly
2. The `DrinkRecipe.objects.create` calls fails and is caught by Django
3. The `post` fails somewhere and is caught by Django

You can debug this by adding some `print()` statement or even a try/except around part you suspect.

Comment: You were right, the form is not valid - I now get the message, but I don't know what is wrong with it. Perhaps `widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()` can't be used with ModelChoiceField?